# prozilla installing error

Tags: installation

i am trying to install prozilla.but this below error is occurred.how can i solve this case?

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/prozilla_2.0.4~quantalbuild1-0tahutek1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/locale/locale.alias', which is also in package locales 2.13+git20120306-3
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for lintian ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/prozilla_2.0.4~quantalbuild1-0tahutek1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Where did you download it? (http://askubuntu.com/q/457152/152405)

Answer (score 0):

Simply type the below command, it worked for my ubuntu 11.10

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite prozilla_2.0.4-build2~tahutek~oneiric_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I think for OP it will be `prozilla_2.0.4~quantalbuild1-0tahutek1_amd64.deb`. And Ubuntu 11.10 is End-of-Life, so please don't post specific to such an older version if possible.