# Where is Prozilla download manager? Who is its developer?

Tags: download-manager

http://sourceforge.net/projects/prozilla => NO download link

ftp://ftp.tu-clausthal.de/pub/mirror/gnu/www/directory/ProZilla.html => :(

I found this [ppa:tahutek-team/prozilla](http://ppa.launchpad.net/tahutek-team/prozilla/ubuntu/dists/), but it does not support Ubuntu Trusty! (I don't know is it provided by the original team or not?)

Is Prozilla an in progress software? I mean is it still in development? Where is its source/binary package?

However, Is this app available for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: The PPA has no Trusty versions available. However, you can contact the developer easily, and ask them your questions yourself.

Comment: use this download manager http://flareget.com/

Comment: @Jos just a suggestion, when you tell someone it is easy to contact someone, might want to provide a link on how to contact that person. :)

Comment: @sohel4r, I need a CLI DM to use it on my project. `wget`, `aria2` and `axel` are available, I wanted to know more about `prozilla`.

Answer (score 2):

Prozilla has had almost no development for a couple years now except for [totosugito](https://github.com/totosugito) moving the code to [github](https://github.com/totosugito/prozilla-2.0.4). I am not aware if he is the original developer or not or what involvement at all he has had with the project. However with that said, the last update on the github page was a year ago.

I would suggest you check out [uGet](http://ugetdm.com) and you can find the Downloads for Ubuntu [here](http://ugetdm.com/downloads-ubuntu). uGet is the #1 Open Source Download Manager for Linux so it is certainly worth looking into.

Comment: And I backed it up in https://github.com/Malsasa/prozilla-2.0.4. I don't want Prozilla source code to be gone.

Answer (score -2):

I downloaded this deb and installed it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. And it's running fine. :)

You can download it from [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0mmtchjntlen9q/prozilla_1.3.7.4-1_i386.deb)

Comment: This is version 1.3; The latest you can find on the net is [2.0.x](http://ppa.launchpad.net/tahutek-team/prozilla/ubuntu/pool/main/p/prozilla/)